# Safari fails to download font for the first time

Tags: web, fonts, safari

Safari fails to download font for the first time (w/o cache), but it's okay after reloading the page. Font files stored are stored on the server.

font-face rules:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: Museo Sans Cyrl;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-display: swap;
  src: 
  url("../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl/MuseoSansCyrl100.ttf") format("truetype"),
  url("../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl/MuseoSansCyrl100.woff2") format("woff2"),
  url("../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl/MuseoSansCyrl100.otf") format("opentype");
}
```

same for other font-weights

[image: Error in dev tools (the same error happens in prod)]

File is downloading if follow the link directly.

Tried playing with font-face, downloading fonts from different files and even from other server

Answer (score 0):

Quite likely you can mitigate this problem by

1. preferring the more compact `woff2` format. Currently safari will load the larger `.ttf` file.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: Museo Sans Cyrl;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url("../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl/MuseoSansCyrl100.woff2") format("woff2"),
  url("../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl/MuseoSansCyrl100.ttf") format("truetype"),
  url("../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl/MuseoSansCyrl100.otf") format("opentype");
}
```

2. adding a `<link>` tag with [preload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/rel/preload) attribute to your HTML `<head>`

```html
<link rel="preload" href="../fonts/MuseoSansCyrl/MuseoSansCyrl100.woff2" as="font" type="font/woff2" crossorigin>
```

From [mdn Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/rel/preload)

> This ensures they are available earlier and are less likely to block
> the page's render, improving performance. Even though the name
> contains the term load, it doesn't load and execute the script but
> only schedules it to be downloaded and cached with a higher priority.